# Reading individual value from jersey client response

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Hi I am calling an API using bellow code

```
 Client client=ClientBuilder.newClient();
 WebTarget target = client.target(dynamicEntityURL);
 String response = target.request().header("Authorization", "Bearer "+readToken.tokenMethod()
                                 .getAccess_token())
                                 .get(String.class);
System.out.println(response);
```

Output is :-

```
{"count":1,"limit":100,"totalResults":1,"hasMore":false,"items":[{"id":"B183C87E-7067-4BC9-BD9D-5AFA145532F3","name":"DynamicEntityTesting","version":"1.0","status":"PUBLISHED"}],"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/skills/?name=DynamicEntityTesting"},{"rel":"canonical","href":"https://idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/skills/?name=DynamicEntityTesting"}]}
```

out of the above output I only need `id` which is under `items`. I know I can create `POJO` and pass it and read the individual value using `getter/setter`. But I will have to create POJOs with all parameters of output. I only need `id` to pass to next `API`. how can I get the value of `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
JsonObject response = target.request().header("Authorization", "Bearer "+readToken.tokenMethod()
                                 .getAccess_token())
                                 .get(JsonObject.class);
          JsonArray jsonArray = response.getJsonArray("items");
          System.out.println(jsonArray.getJsonObject(0).getString("id"));
```